# Is it possible and how to run an SSRS report against an online dynamics CRM data source from a local reporting service in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2013

I need to run an SSRS report against an Dynamics CRM 2013 online organization through an external custom web service written in C# WCF.

As the reporting services of online organizations are not publicly available, this cannot be done through them.

Now I am trying to get to run the same report on a local SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services, having the data source from the online CRM. As credentials in report i add my organization username and password, and fetch xml data connection string to the online organization.

I have tried the following configurations in the data source in reporting services, getting the error messages in them, and having no success:

http://imageshack.com/a/img839/8513/x5h1.jpg

http://imageshack.com/a/img836/7286/umn1.jpg

I am wondering if this can be achieved at all.

My second option is to use an html resource in the organization, as reports can be generated on an online organization through javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Your username should be: `<your username>@<org name>.onmicrosoft.com`, and try uncheck `Use as Windows credential...`

Comment: Have you tried it yourself to see if it's working?

This was a while ago, and at the time the organization was not yet moved to office 365 so onmicrosoft.com post fix was not required. I believe it is not the case. I have also tried all possible options in reporting services.